# How can i define a variable inside of my class if its declared in a function outside of the class

Tags: javascript, json

I created a Leaflet map and i want to create a marker for each element in my json file. But the problem is i dont know how i can define the "nosDonnee" varible inside of my class. My code

```
class carte {
  constructor() {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([45.764043, 4.835659], 12);
    this.calque = L.tileLayer(
      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      { maxZoom: 20 }
    ).addTo(this.map);
    this.marker = L.marker([
      parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lat),
      parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lng)
    ]).addTo(this.map);
  }

  addMarker() {
    for (let i = 0; i < nosDonnee.length; i++) {
      this.marker = L.marker([
        parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lat),
        parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lng)
      ]).addTo(this.map);
    }
  }
}

function ajaxget() {
  let url = new XMLHttpRequest();
  url.open(
    "GET",
    "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=lyon&apiKey=69b9e30a10d230227d189617d1827d3586cf19be"
  );
  url.onload = function() {
    let nosDonnee = JSON.parse(url.responseText);
  };
  url.send();
}

ajaxget();

let nouvCarte = new carte();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make `nosDonnee` a property of your class, then you can use and modify it everywhere in your class.

The ** aren't part of the syntax obviously, but just highlight the changes that I've made to your code.

```
class carte {
  constructor(**donnee**) {
    this.map = L.map("map").setView([45.764043, 4.835659], 12);
    **this.nosDonnee = donnee;**
    this.calque = L.tileLayer(
      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.se/hydda/full/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
      { maxZoom: 20 }
    ).addTo(this.map);
    this.marker = L.marker([
      parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lat),
      parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lng)
    ]).addTo(this.map);
  }

  addMarker() {
    for (let i = 0; i < nosDonnee.length; i++) {
      this.marker = L.marker([
        parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lat),
        parseFloat(nosDonnee[i].position.lng)
      ]).addTo(this.map);
    }
  }
}

function ajaxget() {
  let url = new XMLHttpRequest();
  url.open(
    "GET",
    "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=lyon&apiKey=69b9e30a10d230227d189617d1827d3586cf19be"
  );
  url.onload = function() {
     **let nouvCarte = new carte(JSON.parse(url.responseText));**
  };
  url.send();
}

ajaxget();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add you variable to the constructor and add it as a property to your class.
2. Access that value from within the class using `this.`.
3. Instantiate `carte` within the onload callback, to ensure that the response from your GET async call has arrived. (Otherwise the instantiation will happen before response is obtained.

```js
class carte {

  //Pass this nosDonnee value by param to constructor
  constructor(nosDonnee) {
    this.nosDonnee = nosDonnee;
    //Here is the test output 
    //showing how you can access that variable
    console.log(this.nosDonnee[0]);
    
    //For simplicity of this example I removed
    //the rest of the code
    
  }

}

function ajaxget() {
  let url = new XMLHttpRequest();
  url.open(
    "GET",
    "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=lyon&apiKey=69b9e30a10d230227d189617d1827d3586cf19be"
  );
  url.onload = function() {
    let nosDonnee = JSON.parse(url.responseText);
    //Instead of calling this method outside
    //call it when the async call have finished
    //so you ensure to have response
    let nouvCarte = new carte(nosDonnee);
  };
  url.send();
}

ajaxget();
```